# Add a member to gae application for upload the application

Tags: google-app-engine

I've developed one application and host on Google App Engine. My team member and I are living in different locations, and the application is registered in my login.

Before use of the latest Cloud SDK version GoogleAppEngine-1.9.20, my team member and I are both able to login from respective locations.

But now after installing this newest version of SDK GoogleAppEngine-1.9.20, I am still able to upload my application into GAE, however my team member can not be able to do this at their location.

Any one have any ideas how this could happen ? Any suggestions or advises would be appreciated.

Thanking you.

Comment: Please provide more details about your problem. What deployment environment are you using? Which authentication procedure are you using? Password or Oauth2? It seems that you could be using Oauth2 to upload your application while your team member does not use OAuth2.

Comment: We are develop application in php environment, and application upload using Google App Engine Launcher version GoogleAppEngine-1.9.20.

Comment: I am able to upload app using gae, but my team member is not able to upload an app from their location using same version gae. can I give any permission to him. or any other solution..!!

Comment: Did your team member try to deploy the app through appcfg.py ?

Comment: I have search lots from google.. and finally I got the solution.. Application Owner can give permission to the team members.. use following link.. https://console.developers.google.com/project/<your-app-id>/permissions and add team members emails and access rights... its done...

Comment: @RushiRaval Can you post your answer to your question so that this issue can be closed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have search lots from google, and finally I got the solution.
Application Owner can give permission to the team members. use following link, and add team members emails and access rights... its done...

link: https://console.developers.google.com/project//permissions